# My pepper sauce looks unsafe

Tags: canning, vinegar, olive-oil, botulism

I canned some pepper sauce. It had peppers and green tomatoes. After 3 days of being refrigerated , the peppers are floating on top and has blobs of cloudy material stuck to the peppers. The tomatoes are on the bottom.
I am wondering if adding olive oil has caused this and are they safe

Comment: Welcome to the site. How did you can this, and why is it in the fridge afterwards? Can you please edit and add details on your canning method?

Comment: Can you link to the recipe you followed? That will make it much easier to figure out what might have gone wrong.

Comment: The blobs of cloudy material stuck to the peppers are likely congealed olive oil.

Answer (score 5):

Cloudy material will be fungus growing in the culture. **It is not safe to eat**.

Where the contamination has come from is impossible to work out, there are several steps in the canning process during which a failure in the step could result in the canning not being sterile and growing something.

Comment: If it's peppers & green tomatoes, he would have had to pressure can it to sterilize it.

Comment: @FuzzyChef - yes, still could have got that wrong. Fungal spores are pretty hard to kill, as I am sure you know unless you get temperature, pressure and time above the right values things might not be sterile!

Answer (score 0):

If it is only 3 days in the fridge, it is likely not growth. Alternatively it is just olive oil solidified. To test this, take it and warm it. If it melts into olive oil then it is olive and not fungus.

Answer (score -1):

Contamination is also likely if you placed hot or warm food in the fridge. Was the canned sauce room temperature?